# Из строки получить ZonedDateTime

Tags: java

Есть строка: "2019-11-28T02:25:30.372079"

Не могу подобрать паттерн, что бы получить ZonedDateTime

Делал так:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-11-28T02:25:30.372079", formatter)
```

Получаю: Method threw 'java.time.format.DateTimeParseException' exception.

Как мне получить ZonedDateTime из заданой строки?

Comment: а что в этой строке указывает на временную зону?

Comment: У вас Instant, а не ZonedDateTime в строкею. Потому просто Instant.parse()

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko а как хотя бы instant получить? Он и такой формат не парсит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");

        Date parsedTimeStamp = dateFormat.parse("2019-11-28T02:25:30.372079");
        System.out.println(parsedTimeStamp);

        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2019-11-28T02:25:30.372079Z");
        System.out.println(instant);
    }

}
```

Ну все немного сложнее. Для Instant таки нужна таймзона, хотя бы просто Z в конце, как указатель на +0